# Ajax call failing

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am using Ajax to send information to a server and return a JSON string. This is the code I am using:

```
function getRequests(folder, mode) {
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = singleBook(folder, mode);
xhr.open("GET", "bestreads.php?mode=" + mode + "&title=" + folder, true);
xhr.send(null);
}

function singleBook(folder, mode) {
alert(xhr.responseText);
if (mode == "info") {
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
}
}
```

I have tested my PHP script and I am 100% certain that it properly prints out the correct JSON string for every possible folder name. I have validated the JSON string it creates to confirm this.
However, this code leaves xhr completely empty. I have tried checking the status with xhr.stats but it returns 0, which doesn't make sense to me since I thought it is supposed to return 404 or 200.

This is a school project and I am not allowed to use JQuery, so I need a solution to this that does not use it. I make an Ajax call earlier in my call the same way and it works without any issues, but returns an XML string instead of JSON which makes me think I need to do something else to return the JSON string, but I have no idea what that may be.

PHP code:

```
function createJson($folder) {
$path = "books/" . $folder . "/info.txt";
$infoFile = file($path);
$info = '{"title":"' . $infoFile[0] . '","author":"' . $infoFile[1] . '","stars":"' . $infoFile[2] . '"}';
print $info;
}
```

Comment: show your `bestreads.php` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign a function reference to `onreadystatechange` instead you are invoking the `singleBook` function and is assigning the value returned by that to `onreadystatechange`.

Also need to wait for the ajax request before processing it

```js
function getRequests(folder, mode) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = singleBook(xhr, folder, mode);
  xhr.open("GET", "bestreads.php?mode=" + mode + "&title=" + folder, true);
  xhr.send(null);
}

function singleBook(xhr, folder, mode) {
  return function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
      if (mode == "info") {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is returning the json string but for some reason it all also returning a comment I have outside the start of the PHP code. Do you know why that is?

Comment: In modern browsers, use `xhr.addEventListener('load', singleBook)` is more aesthetic and readable.

Comment: @TheBandit If that comment is outside of your PHP code, it's plain text. Plain text == output. Any output is returned.

Comment: This is definitely what I was looking for but for some reason the json string has new lines in areas that I did not specify new lines (it is making a new line before the end quote and comma). Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @TheBandit that needs to be fixed in the php side, how are you creating the json in PHP

Comment: @ArunPJohny '{"title":"' . $infoFile[0] . '","author":"' . $infoFile[1] . '","stars":"' . $infoFile[2] . '"}'; It validates in any json validator when I add in values in place of infoFiles but when I request it with Ajax is gets messed up like how I described.

Comment: @TheBandit I'm not much familiar with PHP, but why don't you use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: @ArunPJohny I tried that but it's the javascript that is adding in the newlines, in the PHP it does not have the newlines.